# Creating a real-time price calculating form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I'm working on a project which includes an order form which calculates the price of a door in real-time. The problem is that I can't decide what path should I take.

Form inputs will be:

- Frame (Dropdown)
- Door height
- Door width
- Frame Material (Dropdown)
- Door Material (Dropdown)

I was given a list of price tables which are sorted by maximum width & height. The tables then contain prices for each door sorted by door and frame materials.

What languages should I use for this project?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I would recommend to use PHP with jQuery and Ajax, so your app stay secure because you do the calculation on server side and using the data in your database and also you can have real time price by sending data using jQuery and Ajax and retrieve data from your script.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just an indication of the price without further actions, I would just put all data into an JavaScript object and present it that way.

If you are planning on doing serverside stuff with it, you could still use JavaScript to dynamically update everything, but **also** re-calculate it with PHP to avoid people from using the console to change values.